# Fancybox remove blue outline after click

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox

I'am using Fancybox 3 and i can't find or get rid of the default blue outline that is showing after you open and close a image or video in Fancybox. It disappears after you click next to it, but don't want it at all there. Anyone can help?

[image]

[Fancybox 3](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

Comment: you can use * {outline:none;} as beginning in your global css sheet. say its reset code.

Answer (score 1):

In your main css sheet declare as below and check once;

```
* { outline:none; }
```

Comment: Just did that works, but it's weird i first try to set all outline in the fancybox css to 'none' or '0' but didn't work. Putting it on (*) works. ;-)

Comment: Being * is universal selector. Refer: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the blue outline for the examples on the site that you linked. Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

fancybox is not adding any outline, your browser does, because clicked element gets focus. So, either set `backFocus:false` to disable that feature or use CSS to change focus state for your element.